# Откуда лишняя цифра в массиве ? (язык Си)

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, программа должна читать восемь целых чисел в массив,а затем выводит их в обратном порядке.

Например если ввести:

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

то она выводит

> 8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 (откуда появилась первая 8?)

или так

> 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

то же самое

> 8 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11

Вот код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 8
int main ()
{
    setlocale (0,"");
    int number, array[NUM], zero;

    printf ("Введите %d целых чисел: \n", NUM);

    for (number = 0; number < NUM; number++) /* Чтение чисел */
        scanf ("%d", &array[number]);

    for (number = 0; number < NUM; number++) /* проверка */
        printf ("%d ", array[number]);

        printf ("\n");

    for (zero = 0; number >= zero; number--) /* вывод в обратном порядке */
        printf ("%d ", array[number]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас в конце второго цикла значение переменной `number` равно 8, это индекс за последним элементом массива. Поэтому в третьем цикле вы начинаете выводить с индекса 8, это неправильно.

Вы обращаетесь к массиву по несуществующему индексу. Это undefined behaviour, может случиться всё, что угодно, включая креш (и это ещё в лучшем случае) или потерю данных.

Попробуйте так:

```
for (number--; number >= 0; number--) /* вывод в обратном порядке */
    printf ("%d ", array[number]);
```

Или так:

```
while (--number >= 0) /* вывод в обратном порядке */
    printf ("%d ", array[number]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я одно не могу понять, как индекс может быть равен 8?, ведь по условии она не должна превышать 7

Comment: @Dick: Ну смотрите. Если у вас есть цикл `for (number = 0; number < NUM; number++)`, какое будет значение `number`, когда цикл закончится?

Comment: будет равна 7, конечное значение условия будет 7 < 8, 7 больше не инкрементируется по условию, если было бы 7 <= 8, то она была бы равна 8

Comment: @Dick: не-а, будет равна 8. Попробуйте сами и проверьте! Выход из цикла будет как только условие **перестанет** выполняться, а это случится как только значение `number` станет 8.

Comment: Понял)), получается значение number интерементируется до 8, но при этом   тело цикла по условию не выполняется, верно ?

Comment: @Dick: именно так

Comment: @Dick, хочу добавить к замечанию уважаемого VladD. Если Вы будете пользоваться локальными переменными цикла, то подобные ошибки будут появляться гораздо реже.

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не понимал такого извращения

```
for (number = NUM - 1; number >= 0; number--) /* вывод в обратном порядке */
    printf ("%d ", array[number]);
```

Comment: Чем он тебя смущает?